# Open search server : basic questions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search, opensearch

I am evaluating OSS to implement crawling, indexing and searching a mid-sized ASP.NET (MVC4) website.

So far it looks promising.

Here are some basic questions, which I could not find in the docs:

1. German Umlauts:

   the Renderer/Search for German Umlauts 'ä, ü, ö' fails:

   `http://localhost:8080/renderer?use=haas&name=gSearch&query=küche`

   returns

   `"kÃ¼che in the search box with no results - there should be results in the index!"`

   (I created a query "gSearch" with language=German
2. can OSS return Synonyms like "...did you mean..." WITHOUT having to manually insert every thinkable or unthinkable synonym MANUALLY??
3. I did not get results until I added "aspx" in Schema->Parser_list-> HTML -> supported extensions

   is this correct - or should I add another parser for ASP - ... can I have more than one parser for HTML, ASP, PDF...etc...?

   after doing 3. I got results - both aspx and pdf documents... but I did not get a clickable link (filename) for the PDF-Files ??
4. what would be the best way to call search from MVC? Via Webservices...? I do not want to include an IFRAME

Answer (score 0):

It's always troublesome when several different questions are gathered in one., but here's my take on number 4:

I use a WebRequest, very straightforward.

```
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080/select?use=haas&query=kitchen");
        webRequest.Timeout = 10000;
        WebResponse webResponse;

        try
        {
            webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            WriteToEventLog(ex.Message);
        }

        var xmlStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        var reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlStream);
        var doc = XDocument.Load(reader, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

Then you have yourself an XML with the returned fields set up in your OSS index query.